# IE 9 Prompt to allow access data sources across domains

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-domain

My application has huge issues with `internet explorer 9` and below. Because their default settings are that they do not allow access to data across domains.

I feel like I've attempted everything and because each of my clients have their own domain, I am unable to make the hack that makes an iframe.

So my question is:

Is there a way that you can prompt the user to set the setting: `access data sources across domains` to `enabled`?

Comment: I bet _every_ modern browser has this setting by default

Comment: @smnbbrv You may be right however chrome, firefox and IE10+ accepts Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers

Comment: well, you did not write that you are using these headers. Anyway, the best way to fight against old IE - [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). This is quick, dirty and bullet-proof. I am also not sure all your clients will be happy to change the settings, especially in the companies where these settings are protected from non-admin users. This either needs to be done on administrator side or by JSONP as I told above.

Comment: @smnbbrv taken from your link:  JSONP supports only the GET request method. 

Does this mean that i cannot use PUT,POST,DELETE ?

Comment: yes, it does. The JSONP's nature is just requesting a remote JavaScript (which is allowed in cross-domain requests), this could be done only with GET methods. I am really sorry, but this is IE...